# If I mutate the object obtained from Net Core IMemoryCache, will it update its state in the cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using [a MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-setsize-size-and-sizelimit-to-limit-cache-size) in my Net Core code.

First, I place some dictionary in the cache

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>(/* ...some elements to add... */);
cache.Set("MyCacheKey", dict, _cacheEntryOptions);
```

If I retrieve the object from the cache, or just will updating this `dict` object after I called `cache.Set`, will it also update the state of the object in the cache? Say, after the code above I make a call

```
dict.TryAdd(name, 1);
```

Do I need to call `cache.Set()` again or has it been updated already?

Comment: The first paragraph of the page you linked says "Caching makes a copy of data".  The method IMemoryCache.CreateEntry is "Create or overwrite".  So I'm 99% sure based on that alone that changing the dict will NOT magically update the copy in the cache.  You'll have to set it again.

Comment: Yes, but my checks and also answer suggest otherwise. Bad wording it seems. I reported it, I wonder if they fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From below code, to new value is AUTO updated to the cache, you don't need to set the cache value again.

```
        Dictionary<int, string> test = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 0, "a" },
            { 1, "b" }
        };

        _memoryCache.Set("TEST", test);
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("TEST", out object o) && o is Dictionary<int, string> cachedTest)
        {
            cachedTest[0] = "aa";
            cachedTest.Add(2, "c");
        }

        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("TEST", out object o2) && o2 is Dictionary<int, string> cachedTest2)
        {
            var updatedValue = cachedTest2[0]; // this give you "aa". Also the dict contains 3 items.
        }
```

Comment: Interesting!  So although the documentation says "Caching makes a copy of data", the "data" in the memory cache here seems to be "the reference to the object", not a serialized copy of the object.  Excellent demonstration, Alex.

Comment: You can avoid this behavior by using the MemberwiseClone. You need to create a class and store the dictionary in it. In the class,create method Clone(): ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> Clone() { return (ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>)MemberwiseClone(); }.